# Cordova preBuild Faliure

Tags: cordova

I am very new to Cordova, I have been give a project and I am trying to build it with the CLI but I get this build error:

```
>The SDK directory '<PATH on another computer>' does not exist
```

I have the environment variables set up fine but where do I change this variable to point to my version of the sdk?

Comment: Wait a moment, I will consult to my crystal ball...

Comment: Please, read this **before** post a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is the `local.properties` file.

Comment: no that is is the answer the string you need to edit is in local.porperties